# Pipe password argument to mount shell command

Tags: mount, password, fstab, pipe, stdout

#### Status quo

Given are following `/etc/fstab` mount points:

```
//server/app /home/user/server/app cifs noauto,user,vers=3.11  0 0
//server/code /home/user/server/code cifs noauto,user,vers=3.11  0 0
```

These are to be mounted with `user` priviledge (without `sudo`). Given `user` is logged in, `password` currently is interactively prompted - no credentials file and no hardcoded password in `/etc/fstab`.

In addition: all shares have the same credentials `user` with same password.

#### What is the problem?

Let's say, we want to mount all shares at startup. For share `app`:

```
mount ~/server/app # `user` is active
# password interactively requested
Password for user@//server/app:  (press TAB for no echo)
```

The problem is, I would have to type the same password for *all* shares, since it won't be cached.

#### What I tried

```
# type password once and store it in process memory
echo "Enter password for mounts:"
read -s mount_pass
[[ -z "mount_pass" ]] && echo "Password empty, exiting" && exit

# mount all shares - how to feed every mount command with given password?
mount ~/server/app
mount ~/server/code

# My attempts
echo $mount_pass | mount ~/server/app
mount ~/server/app < <(echo $mount_pass)
```

(Excuse my superficial shell knowledge)

Is there a way to pass the password stored in `$mount_pass` to `mount` command, so that it can be automatically read by its standard input and no interactive prompt is opened?

Comment: Seems like you might be using the wrong tool for the job. Looks like a job for `pmount` or `gvfs-mount`

Comment: Thanks for the hinted tools. Unfortunately, it seems that `pmount` is only for block devices, and I need to mount a network share. I cannot use `gvfs-mount` or the newer `gio mount`, as my application needs the share to be mounted via `mount.cifs`/SMB.

Comment: I don't see, what value the linked post is supposed to add to this question. I am already able to mount my shares with `/etc/fstab`. The goal is to mount multiple shares with same password efficiently - while not resorting to a clear text credentials file in `/etc/fstab` (user priviledge preferred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, `mount` via `/etc/fstab` always wants to read the password interactively from the terminal device and there is no solution to pipe it via standard input.

Here is a workaround making use of [GNOME Keyring/`secret-tool`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring) and the `sudo` [`-S`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) option to pass the password via stdin.

1. Store the password in the keyring:

```
secret-tool store --label='share app credentials' share app
# then input your password
```

2. Mount the share

```
secret-tool lookup share app | sudo -S mount -t cifs \
 -o username=bela,password=$(secret-tool lookup share app),vers=3.11,uid=bela \
 //share/app ~/local/share/app
# share := attribute, app := value
```

The caveat is, we have to use `mount` with elevated priviledges. The local `sudo` credentials are assumed to be equal to the remote share server credentials.